# Sequelize: "Include unexpected" on associated table query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Getting error with `documents` table include:

`Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.`:

```
const users = await db.users.findAll({
    where: {
      profile_photo: { [Op.ne]: null },
    },
    include: [
      { 
        model: db.documents,
      }
    ],
});
```

Relevant parts of `documents` define and association:

```
const document = sequelize.define(
    'document',
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()'),
      },
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        references: {
          model: 'users',
          key: 'id',
        },
      },
    }
  );
  document.associate = function(models) {
    models.document.belongsTo(models.users, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'user_id',
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  };
```

PSequel returns foreign key on documents table as:

Key name: 
`documents_user_id_fkey`

Columns:
`user_id`

Foreign table:
`users`

Foreign columns:
`id`

And this psql query returns documents for user:

```
SELECT D
FROM users U
INNER JOIN documents D ON D.user_id = U.id
```

This query includes query DOES work though with `emails` table, and returns emails for user:

```
const users = await db.users.findAll({
    where: {
      profile_photo: { [Op.ne]: null },
    },
    include: [
      { 
        model: db.emails,
      }
    ],
});
```

Relevant parts of `emails` define and association:

```
const Emails = sequelize.define(
    'emails',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()'),
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        references: {
          model: 'users',
          key: 'id',
        },
        allowNull: false,
      },
  );

  Emails.associate = models => {
    models.emails.belongsTo(models.users, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'user_id',
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  };
```

PSequel returns foreign key on `emails` table as:

Key name: 
`emails_user_id_fkey`

Columns:
`user_id`

Foreign table:
`users`

Foreign columns:
`id`

Why isn't the `documents` table behaving the same as `emails`?

Note: I did change the Sequelize association for Documents from name: `id` to `user_id` recently, do I need to re-init that association somehow?

It was changed from:

```
    models.document.belongsTo(models.users, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'id',
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
```

To:

```
    models.document.belongsTo(models.users, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'user_id',
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must reference to the right model name. You either change it to this:

```
const users = await db.users.findAll({
    where: {
      profile_photo: { [Op.ne]: null },
    },
    include: [
      { 
        model: db.document,
      }
    ],
});
```

Or you change it to this:

```
const document = sequelize.define('documents', ..
```

If you define as `document`  you must include `document` and not `documents`.